# Android Program is not correctly accessing external storage?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create an application that saves a log file on Android external storage when a button is pressed

```
 log = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"log.txt");
    try
    {
        pw = new PrintWriter(log);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.out.println(f);
    }
```

At the moment there is no file "log.txt" in the external storage, but when I call log.exists(), it returns true.

Likewise, when log.txt has existed, pw fails to write to it.

Comment: "At the moment there is no file "log.txt" in the external storage" -- how have you determined this, specifically? "when log.txt has existed, pw fails to write to it" -- how have you determined this, specifically? If you are not [telling `MediaStore` about this file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html), it will not appear in file managers for a while.

Comment: I am using file explorer on my PC to access the Android external storage

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the necessary permissions in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

More here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am using file explorer on my PC to access the Android external storage

First, use a `FileOutputStream`. You are welcome to wrap that in an `InputStreamWriter` and other `Writer` objects on top of that, to give you the API that you want.

Second, when you are doing writing to the file, call `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()` on the `FileOutputStream`.

Third, after you `close()` the `FileOutputStream`, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method, to tell the `MediaStore` to index the file. Otherwise, it will not be visible on any file explorer, on-device or on a PC.